# Electric Scooter Hub Motor RPM relationship

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am based out of India and have done a Electric conversion of a ICE 110cc scooter to Electric. Here is the images of the hub motor. [image: Electric Scooter]

The motor is a 1kw BLDC hub motor of 10 inches tyre size.

**Specific Problem**:
The RPM digital cluster reports the wrong speed and distance covered. We have to redesign the system to account for tyre diameter and motor.
Our first attempt was to put a inductive probe, but could not find a good way to mount it yet.

We tapped the signal of one of the hall sensors which generates a 5v signal as it comes in close proximity to the stator magnets. There are 26 magnets in the stator. The controller uses this as a feedback mechanism to power the phases.

My assumption was that I would get one square wave pulse as and when the sensor passes over the magnet, and I would be able to use this to measure both speed and distance traveled.

I used an ESP8266 with an interrupt signal on D2, and the signal is received from only one hall sensor.

I did 4 experiments, manually counting how many rotations elapsed and how many clicks the ESP8266 received.
Here is my table.

Rotations->Clicks-> Clicks/Rotation

13->908->69.85

30->2007->66.90

51->3515->68.92

100->6699->66.99

The error in calculating should go away as the rotations approach higher and higher numbers. It comes close to 67 clicks/rotation, which is a prime and has no relationship to 360 degrees or 26 magnets.

I am planning to do more experiments with still higher total rotations, and maybe get an insight. The scooter is jacked up and cant drive it very fast.

Can you share an insight as to what I could do next to arrive at a logical conclusion, or what else could I do?

Comment: I was going to suggest printing stickers and attach to the speedometer to create a new scale to compensate, but digital readout would prevent this. How about an MCU in between?

Comment: Can you share the hub motor information please? The R->C ratio is not monotonic. Something else has gone wrong.

Comment: @jay Why wouldn't the revolutions to number of hall sensor clicks not be monotonic?

Comment: @winny Yes, we are redesigning the display, and will put a micro in between. To be able to convert the rpm to speed and distance, we need to know how many rpm the motor is spinning at. The intent of the exercise is to understand the relationship between the rotations and the count of excitations of the hall sensor. It comes out to be non linear and non obvious.

Comment: @Rupin , I know, that is my question. I was thinking any part of the motor catalog or data may imply (brag) something meaningful to understand that. There are chips that detect phase angle, not traditional hall sensor.

Comment: @jay Motor comes from a Chinese source with very little data around it. The sensing input of the esp8266 is directly on the hall sensor, its not derived through the motor controller, if that information helps. I haven't see the motor opened, but it doesn't appear that there is any significant intelligence inside the motor.

Comment: @Rupin , it sounds like you need an oscilloscope. Have you probed?

Comment: I have a logic analyser, what would you like me to measure and plot out?

Comment: @Rupin , the moderator suggests to move to chat room. Would you want that? An oscilloscope is better. You want to see the waveform directly on hall sensor. BTW, if the controller is external, then there are signals you can probe, tap out.

Comment: Non-linear sounds very strange. Have you verified on the analog end of things that you (or your MCU) isn't missing any pulses?